# Why is my ternary expression not working?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am trying to set a flag to show or hide a page element, but it always displays even when the expression is false.

```
$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2) ? 'true' : 'false';
...
<?php if ($canMerge) { ?>Stuff<?php } ?>
```

What's up?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is broken because 'false' as a string will evaluate to true as a boolean.

However, this is an unneeded ternary expression, because the resulting values are simple true and false.  This would be equivalent:

```
$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of 'false' is true. You need to remove the quotes:

```
$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2) ? true : false;
```

Comment: This so seems like a reputation-farming attempt. A 3k-rep user who can't differentiate between a string and a boolean, who answers his question a minute after he makes it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Orlando and Ed. This was an issue that caught me out and I posted it for mine and other's benefit. Answering your own questions is perfectly fine per the FAQ. Maybe you should go read it again if it's been a while...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me a reasonable question especially because of the discrepancy in the way PHP works.

For instance, the following code will output 'its false'

```
$a = '0';

if($a)
{
    echo 'its true';
}
else
{
    echo 'its false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'true'` and `'false'` as string. Using a string(non-empty and not `'0'` and not `' '`, because these are empty strings and will be assume as false) as a condition will results the condition to be `true`.

I will write some correct conditions that could be use:

`$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2);`

`$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2) ? true : false;`

```
$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2) ? 'true' : 'false';
...
<?php if ($canMerge == 'true') { ?>Stuff<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$canMerge = ($condition1 && $condition2);
```

then

```
if ($canMerge){
    echo "Stuff";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the problem actually is, which the OP asked.